How to migrate ROS1 code that passes ros::Nodehandle to functions inside constructor
In ROS 1 C++ code, a somewhat popular idiom involves calling functions that takes ros::NodeHandle to initialize members, e.g.
struct NodeParams { /* A bunch of different params */ };

NodeParams GetParams(ros::NodeHandle &nh) { /* Populate NodeParams with nh.getParam */ }

class FooNode {
 public:
  FooNode() : params_(GetParams(pnh_)) {} // Calls GetParams in ctor

 private:
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  ros::NodeHandle pnh_{"~"}; // Ensure pnh_ is constructed first

  // const member is actually malpractice!
  // But we want to highlight that params_ must be set in the member init list
  const NodeParams params_;
};

In ROS2, we would be tempted to replace ros::NodeHandle with rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr, such that our param handling function becomes
NodeParams GetParams(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr pn) { /* defn omitted */ }

But this approach has a fatal issue: If we want to call this function inside the member init list
class FooNode : public rclcpp::Node {
 public:
  // Buggy!
  // shared_From_this appears to be the way to get a Node::SharedPtr from this
  FooNode() : rclcpp::Node("foo"), params_(GetParams(this->shared_from_this()) {}

  // Omitted
};

an exception will be thrown during construction as we know shared_from_this cannot be called during initialization - the class itself hasn't fully materialized and no shared_ptr can point to it yet.
How to solve this issue and properly migrate ROS 1 code using the aforementioned idiom?

This is a commonly encountered issue. You are right in that shared_from_this cannot be called from within the constructor. There are multiple options available:

Is there a specific reason you need access to the shared pointer? Since you are already inheriting from rclcpp::Node class, to access parameters and declare pubs/subs you can simply use the inherited functions like so:

    this->declare_parameter("param1", -1);
    int val = this->get_parameter("param1").as_int();

This works inside the constructor.

You don't have to inherit from Node class, instead Node and Executors can be members of your class and in this case, you can create Node inside the constructor of your class; this Node is fully initialized and can be used to access parameters.
I am by no means an expert on this topic, but the idea I believe was to have all initialization and configuration done in different phases of a node brought up using Lifecycle nodes. Typically, you would do your configuration in on_configure stage of node bring up. An example can be found here: nav2_collison_monitor.

Please take my recommendations with a grain of salt as there might be more suitable alternatives out there.
A working code snippet for recommendation #1
#include <cstdio>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

class Foo : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
  Foo() : rclcpp::Node("test_params", rclcpp::NodeOptions())
  {
    loadParams();
  }
  private:
  void loadParams()
  {
    this->declare_parameter("param1", -1);
    int val = this->get_parameter("param1").as_int();
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Parameter value:%d", val);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
  rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor exec;
  exec.add_node(foo);
  exec.spin();
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}


